# Where clause in the query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can group by Qty but not woitempart. I \tTried to use a where clause but in vain due to this exception:

> Exception: ERROR #50805215 Query failed to execute. GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -206 Column unknown WOITEMPART At line 21, column 7

I need to filter the result set by woitempart (Column). Example: Where woitempart = A00089

```
select part.num as woitempart
    ,(woitem.qtytarget / wo.qtytarget) as woitemqty
    ,(
        select LIST(wo.num, ',')
        from wo
        inner join moitem on wo.moitemid = moitem.id
        where moitem.moid = mo.id
        ) as wonums
from mo
inner join moitem on mo.id = moitem.moid
left join wo on moitem.id = wo.moitemid
left join woitem on wo.id = woitem.woid
    and woitem.typeid = 10
left join (
    select sum(woitem.qtytarget) as labor
        ,woitem.woid
        ,uom.code as uom
    from woitem
    inner join part on woitem.partid = part.id
        and part.typeid = 21
    inner join uom on woitem.uomid = uom.id
    group by 2
        ,3
    ) as labor on wo.id = labor.woid
left join part on woitem.partid = part.id
where woitem.qtytarget < 1200
order by woitempart asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put apostrophes around the string, and use the proper column name:

```
Where part.num = 'A00089'
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should use the original column name in your `WHERE` clause.**

`woitempart` is just an alias you gave to `part.num` in the select statement. As you can see [in this great article by Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/), you don't have access to a `SELECT` alias in the `WHERE` clause because the alias doesn't exist yet since the `WHERE` clause is processed before the `SELECT` clause.  This is also the cause and solution to using `woitempart` in your `GROUP BY`.

The exception means you are trying to use `woitempart` at a time when it doesn't mean anything to the database.  Replacing `woitempart` in your query with `part.num` should fix your problem.  I can't say where that replacement is going to be because your query appears to be dynamically created based on the error, and the query is clearly different than what is posted above because there is no `woitempart` at line 21.

Here is the Logical Query Processing Phases from the blog post above:

> These phases and their orders are given as follows:
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. OUTER
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. CUBE | ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Comment: I removed Alias and used part. num and it actually worked. :) Thanks so much. I have another question. 1.There are duplicates of part.num and I want to remove duplicates and add quantities of those duplicates into one single quantity. 2.Add another field called user who takes care of those part.num.

Comment: Tables are NUM, WOITEMQTY and WONUMS. 
Query is same as above.